# Alternative methods of running ajax submit method

Tags: jquery

Hi everyone I am currently using the below code to run ajax submission on my page and was wondering if it is the most effective way of handling it given the variety of methods used for capturing user data.

What would a better method entail?

This is the JavaScript code I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $("#form").hide(300);
        $.post('run.php', $("#form").serialize(), 
        function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is my form:

```
<form id="booking">
          <table width="600" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="2px" style="font-size: 20px;">
            <tr>
              <th width="296" align="left">Date Of Wedding</th>
              <td width="288"><input name='date' type='text' class='larger' id='date' value='' size='20'/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th align="left">Party Size</th>
              <td><input name='partySize' type='text' class='larger' id='partySize' value='' size='20' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th align="left">Catering Grade</th>
              <td>1:
                <input name='cateringGrade' type='radio' class='larger' value=1 size='12'/>
                2:
                <input name='cateringGrade' type='radio' class='larger' id='cateringGrade' value=2 size='12'/>
                3:
                <input name='cateringGrade' type='radio' class='larger' id='cateringGrade' value=3 size='12'/>
                4:
                <input name='cateringGrade' type='radio' class='larger' id='cateringGrade' value=4 size='12'/>
                5:
                <input name='cateringGrade' type='radio' class='larger' id='cateringGrade' value=5 size='12'/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th align="left">&nbsp;</th>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th align="left">&nbsp;</th>
              <td><input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"/></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var form = $("#form");
        form.hide(300);
        $.ajax({
          url: 'run.php',
          type: form.attr('method'), // POST or GET,
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
             // handle with response
             $("#result").html(data);
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

But it is better to do it in form submit function like following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            form.hide(300);
            $.ajax({
              url: 'run.php', // you can also use form.attr('action') if url is dynamic
              type: form.attr('method'), // POST or GET,
              data: form.serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                 // handle with response
                 $("#result").html(data);
              }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Remove or comment out dateType json. He's obviously using returned data as html and not an object value. I can't find where you parse requred data for the ajax().

Comment: @methusaleh. You already got some good suggestions, but I also would use `$.ajax.beforeSend()` & `$.ajax.error()` methods. 
In case of `$('#form').on('submit', function() {...})` you can hide the form "beforeSend"-ing the ajax-call and in case of errors, you could show the form back

Answer (score 1):

$.post() uses the $.ajax() function, so both are good to go with.

I prefer $.ajax() because I find it more logical and easy to configure.

I would change your script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").bind('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide(300);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'run.php',
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How would I set up `$.ajax()` using the form I have above? Have you got a sample?

Comment: Example given. I also changed event since I find it more logical to capture the submit of the form, rather then a click of a button. Maybe someone tries to submit it through pressing Enter in a input field?